# Prisma ignore gql foreign key error in one-to-many-self-relationship

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, prisma, prisma-graphql

I need help working through this error. I have a one-to many-self-relationship that dictates all the comments/children a post will have. see schema below.

```
    model Post {
      id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
      createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
      description String
      postedBy    User?    @relation(fields: [postedById], references: [id])
      postedById  Int?
      votes       Vote[]
      comments    Post[] @relation(name: "comment") 
      parent      Post? @relation(name: "comment", fields: [parentId], references: [id])
      parentId    Int?  @default(0) 
    }
```

As you can see, the `parentId` defaults to zero. I always want the root post to have a `parentId` of zero to signify that it is a root post because there is no Post with Id 0 for the foreign key to reference.

When I added the one-many-self-relationship with default 0 my prisma populated correctly, ignoring foreign-key errors in my db as seen below.

[image: db screenshot]

The parent field is null? or undefined? because the `parentId = 0` doesn't exist. That is good because those are root posts. The problem is when I try and make a post mutation using gql I get a foreign key error because there is no post with `id` 0. See mutation below.

```
  const { userId, prisma } = context;

  if (userId === null) throw new Error("Not Authenticated");
  const newPost = await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      description: args.description,
      postedBy: { connect: { id: userId } },
      parent: { connect: { id: args.parentId } },
    },
  });
  context.pubsub.publish("NEW_POST", newPost);
  return newPost;
}
```

if I replace `args.parentId = 0` I will get the foreign key error in gql, if `args.parentId = 1` I will not get an error but the post is no longer considered a root post (bad).

can someone please offer me some guidance with this issue? I would like to ignore the foreign key error if possible.

I have looked into the referential actions (seen below) to set a default on post but I don't think my use case is the purpose of referential actions so I am not sure where to look...

```
model Post {
  id             Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  title          String
  authorUsername String? @default("anonymous")
  author         User?   @relation(fields: [authorUsername], references: [username], onUpdate: SetDefault)
}
```

Comment: This seems incredibly hacky and not how relational databases or prisma was intended to be used.  A foreign key should not store a `id` that does not actually exist in the database. This can lead to all sorts of bugs and errors. Why don't you just keep the `author` relation field empty or create a new boolean field like `isRootPost` to identify root posts instead?

Comment: *Why don't you keep the `parent` relation field empty. Sorry typo.